# Can't launch Chromium as executable doesn't exists if customized image is build from Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, chromium, alpine-linux, codeceptjs

```
FROM alpine:latest
# Copy source to container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
# Copy source code
COPY package.json /usr/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/app
COPY . /usr/app
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Environment variables
ENV BASE_URL="Local https url"
ENV PARALLEL_RUN=false
ENV TAG=int
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/usr/lib
# npm install
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN apk add chromium
# Run tests
RUN npm run codeceptjs
```

Above is the Dockerfile. When tried to Build the image from docker file then I am getting below error:

> 13 8.596 Error: browserType.launch: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /usr/lib/chromium-888113/chrome-linux/chrome
> #13 8.596 Try re-installing playwright with "npm install playwright"**

Although, I can see chromium is getting installed at the mentioned path but still it saying "executable not present".

Comment: Do you have `playwright` as dependency in your package.json? It looks like you don't run `npm install` anywhere in your Dockerfile

Comment: I am using RUN apk add --update npm which will install npm. Yes, I have playwright dependency in package.json

Comment: That will install `npm`, correct but it won't install your node_modules. Please add `RUN npm install` after `RUN apk add chromium` and try again

Comment: I tried the above mentioned steps and added RUN npm install but I am still getting below error:


#15 10.76 Error: browserType.launch: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /usr/lib/chromium-888113/chrome-linux/chrome       
#15 10.76 Try re-installing playwright with "npm install playwright"

Comment: Which NodeJS version are you using? Could it be related to https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4033?

Comment: I checked the above solution but it didn't worked. I am using NodeJS version as 15.12.5

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies with using alpine.

According to the playwright developers, there are [no plans to support playwright on alpine](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1986). This makes your whole undertaking more complex. It's correct that you need to provide your own chromium and cannot use the browsers that come with playwright. Therefore, you should set [`PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD`](https://playwright.dev/docs/browsers#skip-browser-downloads) to prevent any (incompatible) browsers from being loaded.

The chromium executable should be in your Docker image under */usr/bin/chromium-browser*. You need to use [playwright's `browserType.launch`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype/#browser-type-launch) to set the path to the executable:

```js
const { chromium } = require("playwright-chromium");
// ...
const browser = await chromium.launch({
    executablePath: process.env.PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH,
});
```

If you want a **simpler solution**, I would suggest using [the Docker image of Zanika](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome#how-to-use-with-playwright), containing chromium and playwright already. [Here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/zenika/alpine-chrome/with-playwright/images/sha256-b57a5d04f7e16881db343bb0c859d3e9b30c7e5737a614ae55e55941468e578d?context=explore) the link to the tag on DockerHub. At the very least you can see it as a reference implementation if you still want to use your own image.

Comment: I tried Zanika docker image but I am getting error as browserType.launch: Failed to launch: Error: spawn /usr/lib/chromium-888113/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT

Comment: can you please share what you try to run with `npm run codeceptjs`. Also the `RUN` command is used during Docker image builds. If you want to run a node script in your Docker container then you have do define an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) command

Comment: What do you mean by you "tried Zanika docker image"? How did you run it? How did you add your code to be run to it?

Comment: Here is the code for npm run codeceptjs in package.json file:
  "scripts": {
    "codeceptjs:local": "npx codeceptjs run",
    "codeceptjs": "if test $PARALLEL_RUN = true; then npm run codeceptjs:workers:tag; else npm run codeceptjs:tag; fi",    
    "codeceptjs:tag": "npx codeceptjs run --grep $TAG",
  "codeceptjs:workers:tag": "npx codeceptjs run-workers $PARALLEL_WORKERS --grep $TAG"
  },

Comment: FROM zenika/alpine-chrome:with-node
USER root
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json /usr/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/app
COPY . /usr/app

# Environment variables
ENV BASE_URL="Local https url"
ENV PARALLEL_RUN=false
ENV TAG=int
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/usr/lib
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install -g ts-node
RUN npm install --force

Comment: # Run tests
ENTRYPOINT ["chromium-browser" "--headless" "--use-gl=swiftshader" "--disable-software-rasterizer" "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]
RUN npm run codeceptjs

Here is the remaining part of docker file as it was not possible to add entire docker file in single comment

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reason why you want to use alpine? Can't you just use the official [codecept image](https://codecept.io/docker.html)?

Comment: Codeceptjs Image size is huge around 4 GB whereas alpine image is in mb's. Sometimes downloading the codeceptjs image from Jenkins Linux agent do takes time and my plan is to have customized image having less size

Comment: Could you please tell how to pass below code in docker file having Alpine base image:

const { chromium } = require("playwright-chromium");
// ...
const browser = await chromium.launch({
    executablePath: process.env.PLAYWRIGHT_CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH,
});

Comment: You write in in a JS file ([example](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/blob/master/with-playwright/src/useragent.js)) and add `CMD ["node", "src/useragent"]` to your Dockerfile. That's how they did it at Zenika

Comment: Thanks. Now only problem I am getting is chromium is getting downloaded with version as  chromium (93.0.4577.82-r0) but its looking for another version
 browserType.launch: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /usr/lib/chromium/chromium-888113/chrome-linux/chrome

I am not sure why there is mismatch in downloading and executing the chromium version.

Comment: @Chals please consider upvoting my answer and/or marking it as accepted answer if it helped you

Comment: +1. Mind having a look at this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122213/executable-path-for-chromium-not-found-when-code-is-deployed. Believe is related but somehow I can't make out how to update my Dockerfile to get it installed and have a path to point to the chromium browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

ARG ENV
ENV Environment=$ENV

WORKDIR "/tests/src/test/functional/FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests"

COPY ["FunctionalTests.csproj", "FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests/"]
COPY . .

        
#Install powershell to playwright scripts
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install wget -yq \
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install powershell -yq


#Build .csproj
RUN dotnet build "FunctionalTests.csproj" \
  -c Release \
  -o /app/build


WORKDIR "/app/build"

# Install playwright dependencies
RUN pwsh ./playwright.ps1 install
RUN pwsh ./playwright.ps1 install chromium
RUN pwsh ./playwright.ps1 install-deps chromium


#Run API tests
WORKDIR "/tests/src/test/functional/FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests"

RUN dotnet test "FunctionalTests.csproj" \
    -c Release \
    -o /app/report
```

this is how I solved the problem