# Executable path for chromium not found when code is deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, playwright

I am using Playwright and Chromium where when a user hits a rest endpoint,

it calls following `test` function:

```
import { chromium } from 'playwright';

const getPlaywrightExecutablePath = () => {
  const executablePath = 'usr/bin/chromium-browser';
  if (deployedToRemote) {
    return { executablePath };
  }
  // no need to override for local
  return {};
};

const test = async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: true,
    ...getPlaywrightExecutablePath(),
  });
};
```

It works fine when I run this locally. I can actually not even need to override

`executablePath` locally and it would still work during which the path will default to following on my Mac:

```
~/Library/Caches/ms-playwright/chromium-1076/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS
```

It fails in finding the executable path for chromium when I deploy to my cloud pod which is linux based.

I get the error:

> Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /home/node/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1076/chrome-linux/chrome

How can I address the path Chromium. What would be the correct path?

Or should I install something extra?

This is my `Dockerfile` if needed.

```
FROM artifactory.company.com/proxy/docker-alpine-node16-runtime:latest

COPY node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . ./dist/

ARG PORT=8080
ENV PORT ${PORT}

EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

This is the script in my package.json file. This gets called during my github actions steps so it does gets installed.

`npx playwright install` does the `chromium` install.

```
"start": "npm install && npx playwright install"
```

Question is where is the path or since is remote on a pod, I need to handle this differently?

Note that the application works fine in other aspects and is deployed. Issue is specific to finding `chromium` path for `playwright` to be able to work / scan.

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "playwright": "^1.36.2",
    // many other dependencies not related to playwright
  }
```

Comment: Is that really necessary? npx playwright install --with-deps should actually do everything needed to execute the tests also on CI. See also https://playwright.dev/docs/ci

Comment: @MichaelS. I am scanning it via a rest service not ci. npx playwright test won't do for me. I have other logics to use other libraries that happens after I scan with playwright. Which works locally. Question of how to get Chromium working when I deploy to a pod.

Comment: Upgrading "playwright-core" package version fixed this for me when `npx playwright install` didn't work.